# How do I place specific rows on a Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report which invokes a stored procedure to return a table containing an assortment of values.

I wish to place various rows of this table in assorted positions on the report. To this end, I create Formula Fields with the data items specified in the formula thus:-

```
{sp_MyReport.Column1}
```

and spatter them about the report as necessary. To select different rows, I change the selection formula to:-

```
{sp_MyReport.IdColumn} = 2
```

But when I do this, the record selection in all the other formula fields is changed to match, so I can only ever have one row of data items displayed.

First, is creating Formula Fields the right way to go about this (I have to keep blanking out the text in the header which suggests it might not the intended use)?

If so, how do I get different Formula Fields to display different rows?

If not, what should I be doing?

Comment: if you are trying to only invoke only headers and values then easy way would be use cross tabs where put `{sp_MyReport.IdColumn}` on columns and values on rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a subreport containing the stored procedure and then cache the values with shared variables.

Define a variable per value that should be shown in the main report and assign the corresponding value to it.

The formula in the subreport would look as follows:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar myValueX;
Shared NumberVar myValueY;

//assign the corresponding value to the variable
If {sp_MyReport.IdColumn}=2 Then myValueX := {sp_MyReport.ValueColumn}
If {sp_MyReport.IdColumn}=3 Then myValueY := {sp_MyReport.ValueColumn}
```

To show the value in the main-report, create a formula as follows:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar myValueX;
```

The subreport should be placed inside the report-header section, as variables are always evaluated from top to bottom.

To hide the subreport, just decrease the size until it's small enough to fit somewhere on the report without "destroying" the report design.

(Do not suppress the subreport, because then it will not be evaluated.)